# JQuery IF document url = "../products.html" Then do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements

How can I get the document url and compare it with an conditional branch?

Pseudo Code:

```
If document url = "../products.html"
Then do this piece of code();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working with loaded html, you can try

```
if(window.location.pathname == "products.html"){
//do something here
}
```

location.pathname returns the file name or path specified by the location.

In addition, You can get the file name by

```
var p = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var filename = p[p.length-1];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer WaiLam but this does not work.. The result of this fork is, that the page reloads like everytime.. I cant help me right now. I thought an IF is just for conditionals.. and now it actually does something.. is there another way to just get the url of the browser and then compare it with an if statetement?

Comment: It returns the path not the filename, by this you have to compare with `/products.html` (or whatever the absolute path may be)

Comment: @Dr.Molle: yeah.  @Mr. Freeman: In addition, You can get the file name by var p = window.location.pathname.split("/"); filename = p[p.length-1];